# Problems with libgtk-3-dev and libgtk-4-dev

Tags: gcc, gtk, pkg-config

I recently installed the `libgtk-3-dev/libgtk-4-dev` apt packages on my machine.
When using the `<gtk/gtk.h>` header in my C code and compiling, GCC throws an error saying that it cannot find the header files.

The error is obscure, I cannot find a solution anywhere, Stack Overflow misunderstood my question and subsequently closed it, and I have no idea what to do.

**Command**:

```
gcc pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 -o myprogram main.c pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

**Output**:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--cflags’
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--libs’; did you mean ‘--libs=’?
```

These are the commands and the output.
`pkg-config` is installed on my system.

Answer (score 1):

`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` are *commands that generate* compiler and linker flags, rather than being flags themselves, for example:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

To use them on the `gcc` command line you must wrap them in [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#index-command-substitution) shell syntax - in bash that would be:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) -o myprogram main.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

or (with the older "backtick" syntax):

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o myprogram main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```